# Java | Apache Tomcat 9 | Read keystore from memory

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, tomcat9

Is there a way in Apache Tomcat 9 (Java) to read a keystore for SSL encryption from a variable, meaning without the detour of saving the keystore to a file and then specifying the file path as property?

At the moment I pass the keystore into Apache like the following code:

```
Connector connector = new Connector();
connector.setScheme("https");
connector.setProperty("keyAlias", "alias-test");
connector.setProperty("keystorePass", "testpwd");
connector.setProperty("keystoreType", "PKCS12");
connector.setProperty("keystoreFile", "keystore.pfx");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an already configured `KeyStore` you need to use the appropriate *setter* methods, which since Tomcat 8.5 are:

- [`SSLHostConfig#setTrustStore`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLHostConfig.html#setTrustStore-java.security.KeyStore-) for the trusted certificates,
- [`SSLHostConfigCertificate#setCertificateKeyStore`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLHostConfigCertificate.html#setCertificateKeystore-java.security.KeyStore-) for the keystore containing the server certificate.

This sums up to something like this:

```java
       final KeyStore trustStore = ...
       final KeyStore keyStore = ...
       // Certificate
       final SSLHostConfigCertificate certificate = new SSLHostConfigCertificate();
       certificate.setCertificateKeystore(keyStore);
       certificate.setCertificateKeyAlias("mykey");
       certificate.setCertificateKeyPassword("secret");
       // Host SSL configuration
       final SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
       sslHostConfig.setTrustStore(trustStore);
       sslHostConfig.addCertificate(certificate);
       // Connector
       final Connector connector = new Connector();
       connector.setScheme("https");
       connector.setSecure(true);
       connector.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig);
       connector.setProperty("SSLEnabled", "true");
```